# Bootstrap panel-footer issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a chat application using Bootstrap as a base and `fluid-container` because it needs to be a 100% height and width app but it seems that Bootstrap does not like this so I've ended up with some custom CSS to sort it.

The idea is that there are two panels shown on the page, the chat panel and the users panel and the `panel-body` of both should overflow automatically inside itself.

The problem is that now I am also using `panel-footer` and it's created this strange problem, see here in the screenshot.

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.panel-body {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.panel-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

By the way, I am complete beginner in custom CSS so if I am making it more confusing then it needs to be, and it can all be simplified, please also tell me that! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Can you create a demo of your issue? Unfortunately screenshot won't help us find the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.panel-footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Is there any reason why positioning the panels body and footer abolute? When giving the body a height the footer automatically sticks to the bottom

Comment: Without that I found that the 'send message' form did not stick to the bottom.

Comment: As I said: Give the `.panel-body` the fixed height, the footer will automatically stick to the bottom.

Comment: That sorted it. How come adding '0' sorted it?? I'll accept!

Comment: You already got `bottom: 0;` this alligns the bottom of your element to the bottom of your parent with 0px margin, same goes for left and right, since your element does not own a fixed width it will extend so it can furfill both left and right

Comment: There is no height in my code since I've just adapted to your code, I just gave you a different solution with that, sorry if I didnt make that clear. You can give your `.panel-body` a certain height, the footer will automatically adjust.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue, except that my footer ends up affixing itself to the bottom of the PAGE, not the panel in question. My HTML (everything stripped down to bare bones for testing while I put this together) and minimal CSS (again, everything stripped down to barest while I get this working) are below.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:100%;border:1px solid pink;"> <!-- border so I can see what's up -->
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>Select or create case</h4>
</div>

<div class="panel-body" id="caseSelector">
<!-- empty during testing so as not to muddy the test-->
</div>

<div class="panel-footer case-panel-footer" style="border:1px solid cyan;"> <!-- border so I can see what's up -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary case-action-button" type="button" disabled="" data-action="select">Open case</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary case-action-button" type="button" data-action="new">Create new</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

```
.case-panel-footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

I simply can not get this panel-footer to sit at the bottom of the panel's containment area, even though the pink border clearly shows the panel is taking up the whole region available to it in the container.

[image: Pic of the layout]